# Passing data to a modal in Blazor

Tags: html, razor, blazor

Is there some way to transfer multiple data from one page to a modal using Razor syntax? Example I have a table with several columns and rows. In one of the columns there is a button that you can use to edit the data. I want the data from this line to be transfered over into the modal so that I can edit it.

Comment: Your "row" should map to a class entity in a List. And then you can pass that entity.

Comment: Have a look at my TemplateModal. You can see how im passing a model to the same modal on this page : https://github.com/BrianLParker/HowToModal/blob/master/HowToModal/Views/Pages/ModalListExample.razor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility is to do everything in a single page: the grid and the dialog. (This dialog is certainly a div).

```
@page "/{Langue}/OrderList"
<div class="content">
    <div class="container">
        <Components.Grid 
                    Id="grid-order-list"
                    ListViewRecords = "new List<int> { 20, 50, 100 }"/>
    </div>
</div>

@if (LineDetails != null)
{
    <!-- Modal Large -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="large-modal">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
                    <h6 class="modal-title">@ModalTitle</h6>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body text-center">
                    <div class="modal-body-inside" style="height: 85vh; overflow-y: auto; padding: 60px 50px 70px;">
                        <UserControls.LineDetail Source="LineDetails " />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal -->
}

@code {
private MyNameSpace.LineDetailsClass LineDetails;
}
```

As you can see, as long as `LineDetails` is null, the user see only the table. When clicking on the details button, you have to populate `LineDetails`. So the modal will be shown. `LineDetails` should be binded to somme textboxes, ... When the user clicks on a button in the modal, you get the needed info in LineDetails and you reset it to null.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your own posts. When you post here, you give SO the right to distribute the content under CC-by SA 4.0. Any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that your class name is Person, It is your Button code :

```
foreach(var item in Items)
{
...
<td><button type="button" @onclick="@Update(item)">Edit</button></td>
...
}
```

Now we have a model for the Selected Item like this :

```
@code{

Person SelectedItem {get;set;}

void Update(Person selectedItem)
{
SelectedItem  = selectedItem;
}
```

Now you can access you SelectedItem everywhere include modals.

Comment: Or just `<button type="button" @onclick="()=>SelectedItem = item">`

Comment: How to SelectedItem on Modal Pop up view

Answer (score 1):

Guy, Henk and Ali all have the right idea.  **I'd like to add, though, that you can add @onclick to almost ANYTHING-- a div, a table row, etc.**

The general pattern is to have a `List<SomeClass> AllItems`, then a single `SomeClass SelectedItem`, then a null check.

**YourModalControl.razor**

```
<div>Show something from SelectedItem: @SelectedItem.DisplayString</div>
<button @onclick="CloseMe">Close</button>
@code{
    [Parameter]
    public SomeClass SelectedItem {get; set;}
    
    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<SomeClass> SelectedItemChanged{get; set;}
    
    async Task CloseMe(){
        SelectedItem = null;
        SelectedItemChanged.InvokeAsync(SelectedItem);
    }
}
```

**ConsumingPage.razor**

```
@if (SelectedItem is not null){
    <YourModalDisplayControl @bind-SelectedItem="SelectedItem" />
}
@else foreach (var item in AllItems){
    <div @onclick="()=> SelectedItem = item">@item.DisplayString</div>
} 

@code {
    List <SomeClass> AllItems {get; set;}
    SomeClass SelectedItem {get; set;}
}
```